# How to run multiple functions inside a foreach loop

Tags: php

I would like to run a foreach loop with three functions inside of it but only the first function runs.

Here is my code

```
function import_events() {
    global $wpdb;
    $query_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'options';
$options = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT option_name, option_value FROM $query_name WHERE option_name LIKE 'event_url%'");
// array of option names
 $i=1;
foreach ($options as $key => $row) {
    $url = $row->option_value;
    $city_name = $row->option_name;

    import_venues($url);
    import_organizers($url);
    import_events_calendar($url);
}
echo"The Import Is Finished";

wp_die();
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What do you have in functions?

Comment: @timiTao You were right, the issue was in one of my functions. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Then please, add you own answer and explain problem, that you got @Top-Bot

Comment: Can you share the contents of the 3 functions that you tried to execute in order to see what each one returns?

Comment: Thanks! you were on the right track but I already solved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your limited information there may be several possible causes to why the two remaining functions aren't running.

**#1:**
If your code outputs the "The Import Is Finished", then your functions are simply not doing what you ment for them to do. Perform more debug inside those functions.

**#2:**
If your code stops running at some point, it has probably stopped working due to a fatal error. Find the file named "error_log" (no extension) and see the entry with the most recent timestamp to determine if it may explain why your code stopped working.

**#3:**
Perhaps you're simply not seeing any errors. Since you're obviously working with WordPress, the error_log should end up in either /error_log or in /wp-admin/error_log.
While debugging, make sure to edit your /wp-config.php and define('WP_DEBUG', true) instead of false to enable error-logging.

Comment: #1 was spot on! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you're wanting to run functions you have in the same page which I'm assuming are due to the names you are using use these 3 lines to execute them within the for loop

```
$this->import_venues($url);
$this->import_organizers($url); 
$this->import_events_calendar($url);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it was actually an error in one of my functions.

Comment: Awesome man good spot

Answer (score -1):

The problem ended up being in the function `import_events_calendar($url)`

The function was not returning anything which looked like it was not running but it really was just returning nothing.

Thanks for all the help!